# Going live again in Dialogflow with legacy skill after upgrading to V2 on the Actions on Google side

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I made some modifications in Dialogflow on a legacy Actions on Google skill.

Namely I switched to the V2 protocol on the AOG side since V1 is going away in February. Again, I only changed the Dialogflow to/from Actions On Google protocol version.

Can you tell me how do I go live with this? The skill is a legacy skill. It is using the V1 Dialogflow protocol (fulfillment side), so the new versioning beta feature will not work.

The AOG console says *"You modified Actions, but have not created a release for the new draft."* I can't find anything to start promoting a new draft.

I'm stuck.